# IE9 css media queries not working properly...Works fine everywhere else

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/BMz9U/embedded/result/) in IE9 and try resizing the browser. As you can see the error message doesn't work properly. It works fine in Webkit, Firefox and Opera so far.

This is my current code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #my-form label {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
  }
  #my-form .error {
    position: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  #my-form .error:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -16px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #313b53 transparent;
  }
}
```

What could be the problem? I can't seem to figure it out. IE9 is the only one that doesn't work as expected...

Comment: The media query itself works. It's the styles that are giving problems.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. The width is not getting set properly either. Any ideas about what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Just in case, check this (the answer) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#10305733

Comment: I got a second of excitement but that didn't work...

Comment: Sorry. couldn't test as I have no IE but I hoped I could help :(

Comment: @elclanrs : The (max-width: 480px) constraint is not getting applied in IE because of which the styles are not getting applied in IE and so positioning remains unchanged.

Comment: The fiddle is private; needs login.

Comment: That's weird...it should work. I solved my problem tho. I'll post the answer soon

Comment: @tomByrer: The login form *is* the demo. This link should be less confusing: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/BMz9U/

Comment: As a side note, it's recommended to use relative units on media queries (like `em`). Absolute units are weirdly handled by some mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. It seems like there were two things causing problems with IE. First I moved the default code for `errors` to another another media query for 481 and more:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  #my-form .error {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    right: -171px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

And then I used floats instead of `inline-block`. Seems like IE still has problems with `inline-block`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #my-form label {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
  }
  #my-form .error {
    float: left; // Here
    clear: left;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/BMz9U

Comment: Thanks for the update!
If you're interested, the "This field is required" bubble does not engage in IE8, which is used by around the same number of IE9 users now; about 12%, depending on who you listen to:

http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-200807-201204

http://www.getclicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/internet-explorer/

http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8. Could you try again?

Comment: @elclanrs I posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16658482/703717) and I just now stumbled upon your question.So i tried moving the default code to another another media query like you suggest here...but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this issue by adding a js file [respond.src.js](http://www.mockbox.net/website-tips/511-internet-explorer-8-media-screen-not-working) in the header