# IE rips decimals after two places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a situation where i'm giving `width` to a `div` dynamically using `jQuery`. Everything is working good with moz and ff since they are taking `100/7+"%"` as `14.2857%` where as IE is taking it as `14.28%` which is screwing up my UI as 14.28*7 is only 99.96.

is there a solution to make my ie take three or four decimals?? I've tried rounding my output to three, also tried using `toFixed(3)` which are not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about `Math.round()`

Comment: no use.. i've tried the same @Pavlo even if i try rounding to three ie is taking two decimals

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Mine returns: `"14.285714285714286%"` for `100/7+"%"` (IE 11)

Comment: pls try giving this value as width to a div using jquery. in general if you are calculating, it is returning a good value.

Comment: `Math.round(14.28*7)` the result will be `100`. Also, read [JavaScript round() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp)

Comment: well i will try now and tell @pavlo

Comment: How you are giving the width? Can you show your code?

Comment: Probably you do have your own reasons to do it through JS / jQuery, but normally controlling the layout through pure CSS is... more elegant.

Comment: As each browser on each device type will eventually do the rendering, it will matter less what your end result will be, decimal wise. This post shows that: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: Use "user2728841" suggestion and you will always get "same" values.

Comment: Some more reading why you should do your own "rounding" to make sure it looks how you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: @GreenWizard - Did you try using `width: calc(14.2857% - 1px)` - that should sort out rounding bugs - see also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16658482/703717)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you work in pixels instead. Since you are using jQuery anyway, you have access to $(window).width() and $(screen).width(), or $(parentelement).width() so there's your 100%. Then all pixel measurements are guaranteed to be integer by definition.

then

```
$("#mydiv").width($(window).width() / 7);
```

Maybe not the solution you wanted but we have all our developers work in pixels as a standard. We find that works well in practice.

Comment: +1 Yeah u r correct but unpleasantly this is now my condition... i'm supposed only to use pecentage.