# IE not respecting width when given dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, width

In my Previous question [IE rips decimals after two places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167027/ie-rips-decimals-after-two-places?) I've asked if I can change the number of decimal places that ie i taking. as an experiment i've tried giving width dynamically to a `div` in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/r3cud/2/).

Please open the above fiddle in IE and also in any other browser.

I want to know why this is happening in IE and not in rest.Please help.

This may also gives me a hope in deducing an answer for my prev question.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm using IE10

Comment: why on earth have i got a -1???? am i not clear??? needs some explaination?? i'm not good at english

Comment: It's possibly an issue with that version of jQuery (1.10.1)? http://jsfiddle.net/r3cud/4/ Using 1.11.0 works fine - in JSFiddle anyway.

Comment: Yes I found the same as Nick R - even when I comment out the code inside the ready handler, it still errors and throws up a debugger in IE. 1.11.0 fixed it for me also.

Comment: thanks but y only ie???

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("div").css("width", myWidth);
```

This could also be the jQuery version issue. 
I used     `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Make sure the jQuery that you are using is accessible. Its throwing a console error in the fiddle too. 
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @GreenWizard: its a console error .. SCRIPT5: Access is denied.. check it. The jQuery is not reachable.