# Links not working in IE9 and Chrome - Browser Issue?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, joomla

I have a Joomla website and some JavaScript functions.

In the footer of Joomla page I have links added from
https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing?where=website&type=bm&clickbacks=1&frm=home&analytics=0&bm=tb14#.T6T4Q-v9Mhs

But I am facing an issue that these links do not work for IE9 and Chrome browsers.
The rest all are supporting it.

If I remove the image slider jQuery from the page, it is working fine, but due to that slider these buttons are not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the headers ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly

Comment: @dystroy not working by this way

Comment: it is working in Firefox but not working Chrome and IE9

Comment: dear, see my answer i have got your solution

Answer (score 1):

Enable you Javascript of Browsers !!
IF you don't have idea , follow the steps

On browser :

1. Tools ->  Internet Options
2. Security ->  Click on  " Custom level " tab
3. Scroll down , thr you will get the Scripting tabs
   Enable that
4. close browser , then again check it

Answer (score 1):

this is because you may not using server. Use Wamp serve(it have apache server) then your link will work just past you php or html file in www folder in wamp server then run

[image]

**Note**  *if you open page directly from your local drive link wont work*

your website is working fine in chrome

[image]

[image]

Comment: ya i got your problem its because that if we dont use local server the data of link wont display

Comment: i have created website in joomla. Now my issue is that In Ie9 and Chrome My Jquery Conflict for Slider Plug in and Facebook share as show in image.. I have used Jquery Image Slider. I must have to use this jquery. Please Give Me solution that my both scripts run on all browsers..

Comment: there is not problem in your script the problem is that if we don't use local server over link can not get data or image form internet if you put your code on the server you get the images

Comment: could you please provide the url

Comment: sorry for late replay. its working fine i have uploaded image

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 2.5, its the global configurations that need to be set for links to work. Use en-UK language only and then, in global configurations, SEO panel on the upper right side, set each selection to yes, either one at a time or all at once. In the alternative, set them all to no.

If that does not work, begin unpublishing all those extensions, plugins and modules you have added in which make Joomla! into Junkla! Actually Joomla! works best with less baggage.

Unforgivably, there are not enough delete buttons on the menus.