# Conditional comment for IE=9 compatibility mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

I'm using the following conditional comment to notify users thet they are running a non-supported browser version.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

I noticed that this comment is being triggered on IE9 Compatibility mode as-well what was not my attention.

Is there a way to make IE9 Compatibility mode an exception or to distinguish it and IE7 mode from regular IE7 so that I can customize the message for them?

Comment: Is it still triggered when you set the headers provided in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly ?

Comment: BTW, it's generally better to explicitly test in js for the ability of a specific feature than testing for a browser/version.

Comment: meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` does not change the behavior

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to check compatibility mode is:

```
try{ JSON } catch (e){ alert("Compatibility Mode Detected")  }
```

This works because the JSON object is unavailable while in compatibility mode.

Comment: This is no longer true - at least with IE 11. `JSON` does exist with IE11 in compatibility mode.