# CSS / HTML Internet Explorer set span width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Just a short question...

I have a span container which is correctly set in FF with following options:

```
<span id="qmmenue" style="left: 0px; top: 2852px; color: #777777; line-height: 12px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color="#0000ff", Direction=0, Strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color="#0000ff", Direction=45, Strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color="#0000ff", Direction=135, Strength=3); position: absolute; zoom: 1; max-width: 500px; background-color: white;" jQuery17207240081996974917="9">
```

In this span, there is an image and two p elements.

My problem is that in Firefox the box is only at the minimal width.
Internet Explorer shows the box in about 80% of the screen, and most of it is empty.

Here a screenshot of FF and IE:

http://s16.postimage.org/i2ak9xj1x/firefox.png
http://s16.postimage.org/fmdc9tqd1/internetexplorer.png

Any ideas about that?

It should be consitent at minimal width for InternetExplorer , but if possible cross-browser ;-)

// edit : i tested it in IE9 , it have to work for >IE8
it seems to be no issue of block or inline-block. same result in both versions

Comment: This question is of avearge length :P

Comment: Hard to analyze without fiddle. But check your headers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly

Comment: What's your question?  We can see that the width is inconsistent from your screenshots, which is helpful.  Do you want the span to be consistent with IE, or FF, or something else?

Comment: If you want to have consistent results, remove all MS specific things like `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow`.

Comment: yeah not possible because i have no other way to implement a glowing shadow in IE8 ^^

Comment: A `span` should not be used here, since it is to hold inline elements, both `<p>` and ` <img>` are not inline elements. You should be using `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something works in other browsers but not in IE9, chance is that your header isn't correct. Check with this one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Be careful that it won't make it magically all compatible with IE8.

And seriously... using Word to produce directly served HTML is not a viable long term solution...

Comment: yeah i know thats no over the top solution, but its a given document and i have to use it like that. in my company thats a standard of publishing manuals in that way (pdf+html). so, no way :-/ i just tried to improve the results ;-) (f.e. in using js (jquery) to generate menues, etc )

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you testing. You need to set a conditional style for IE to `display:block` (inline-block is not supported by older IE versions)

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Oh if forgotten to tell, im sorry. 
It HAVE to work for IE8 but im actually testing with IE9...

i have tested it btw with :

<span id="qmmenue" style="left: 0px; top: 6464px; color: #777777; line-height: 12px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; display: block; filter: progid:........) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color="#0000ff", Direction=135, Strength=3); position: absolute; zoom: 1; max-width: 500px; background-color: white;" jQuery1720011663576259020147="9">

== with display:block;

no reaction, same result :(

Comment: oh yeah,... its the doctype.....

a pitty i cant edit the header because its an output of MS Word :( , but thanks a lot.

<!DOCTYPE html> on top fixed it ^^°°

Comment: Ok, that's frequently the problem. I posted my comment about the headers as answer.