# jQuery width not working in IE

Tags: jquery, width

I have this in my HTML (not dynamically added or anything like that):

```
<div id="TEST" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
```

and when I do this: `alert(jQuery("#TEST").width());`

... it alerts 1280 in IE! It's alerting 600 in Chrome - what could be messing with this?

These are the only styles applied:

[image]

**EDIT**
I've even tried this and still 1280...

```
jQuery("#TEST").width(600);
alert(jQuery("#TEST").width());
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

Okay, I have looked inside the jQuery implementation and it is because it is returning true from this if statement:

```
if ("scrollTo" in elem && elem.document) ? // does it walk and quack like a window?
```

WHY does my div "walk and quack like a window"?

Comment: If by IE you mean IE9, it may be [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly).

Comment: if I put it on jsfiddle it shows 600 in each of browser. http://jsfiddle.net/VCdGt/5/

Comment: @uDaY You're right. Something else in my script / css must be messing with it somehow, but there don't seem to be any other styles applied, and my JS doesn't touch it.

Comment: @codingkiwi.com See my edit below in answer.

Comment: @Terry Getting there, see my recent edit...

Comment: @codingkiwi.com I have no idea what your edit means...

Answer (score 4):

Would need to see the rendered component to see where the styles are coming from, but you should read about `outerWidth`.

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

**Edit**: After seeing your updated screenshot, you should make the element block level or inline-block level.  Setting the width of an inline element will not provide desired results because it changes based on the element's positioning.

More about inline vs. block elements here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

PS. I know a `div` is a block element, is something in your code forcing it into an inline?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe get the `CSS` width?

```
alert($("#TEST").css("width"));
```

Comment: As far as I know this is same as calling `width()` but with units