# IE9 css issue, forced to use float:left / float:right

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I'm having a bit of an issue with IE9 and just can't figure it out, I'm creating a button in CSS with a linear gradient, it displays perfectly in Chorme, Firefox and Safari but just not in IE9

http://ubizzo.co.uk/img/ie9.png

http://ubizzo.co.uk/img/ch-fi-sa.png

First image link is IE9, second image link is every other browser, the only way I can get it work is if I add float:left or float:right in the css as below but then that obviously screws up the layout, I've tried to use float:none but that doesn't work either, I've tried this in a blank html file just to rule out any conflicting css but still doesn't work :-s

```
.purchase {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}

.purchase a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: auto;
    **float: left;**
    border-image: initial;
    text-align: center;


    border: solid 1px #189199;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #19d7e3, #12A4B3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#19d7e3), to(#12A4B3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #19d7e3, #12A4B3);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#19d7e3', endColorstr='#12A4B3');
}

.purchase a:hover {

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #12A4B3, #19d7e3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#12A4B3), to(#19d7e3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #12A4B3, #19d7e3);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#12A4B3', endColorstr='#19d7e3');

    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Adam.

http://jsfiddle.net/gdmP8/    - notice that the button only displays once you've addded float:left/right

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML? Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo of the problem?

Comment: Try putting in 'position:relative;' instead of 'float'.

Comment: your question still appearing as a unanswered i have seen that there is valid working answer please approve answer thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply this css thi will work in all browser i have check in chrome, Firefox, safari, opera, ie-7, ie-8, ie-9

```
background: #12a4b3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #12a4b3 0%, #19d7e3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#12a4b3), color-stop(100%,#19d7e3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #12a4b3 0%,#19d7e3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #12a4b3 0%,#19d7e3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #12a4b3 0%,#19d7e3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #12a4b3 0%,#19d7e3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#12a4b3', endColorstr='#19d7e3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Hi CSS Guy, thanks for the reply, although this method does display the button in IE9, it doesnt apply the gradient only the solid colour - background: #12a4b3; /* Old browsers */

Comment: i have checked same code in all browser and it's working fine will you please shared jsfiddle link so i can better understand..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/GcYPy/ check this i have changed just link <span><a href="#" class="purchase">Buy Now</a></span>

Answer (score 0):

Float problems in IE 9 are usually due to a bad header. Check with this one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

*Taken from [IE9 Float with Overflow:Hidden and Table Width 100% Not Displaying Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly) 
 (not sure if duplicate)*

And you probably should use the now standard `linear-gradient` (or at least `-ms-linear-gradient` and `-o-linear-gradient` instead of just using moz and webkit specific gradients).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have this same problem in Opera, why don't you just stick to a simple button image rollover for IE?