# Issue with width in IE9 and older browsers

Tags: html, css

I don't know how people test if their site is compatible with old browsers. I have a top menu with `width:100%` that works correctly in firefox but fails in IE9.

Here is the css:

```
.topslidemenu {
     font-size: 11px;  
     font-weight: bold;  
     height: 27px; 
     line-height: 9px; 
     width: 100%; //950px
}
```

when it runs on IE9, the menu width is shortened.

Comment: Make the question more specific, your problem is `menu width shortened in IE9` , add relevent `HTML` and `CSS`, specify the `DOCTYPE` you are using. Cheers!

Comment: Impossible to see the problem without the rest of the code. It's better if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This might solve your problem, at least on IE9 (not on IE8) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#10305733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons：
1.`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
2.In the case of a scrollbar being placed on an edge of the element’s box,
it should be inserted between the inner border edge and the outer padding
edge. Any space taken up by the scrollbars should be taken out of (subtracted
from the dimensions of) the containing block formed by the element with
the scrollbars. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

Try this:

```
.topslidemenu {
     font-size: 11px;  
     font-weight: bold;  
     height: 27px; 
     line-height: 9px; 
     width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight > this.parentNode.scrollHeight ? '100%' : parseInt(this.parentNode.clientWidth) + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without more code. IE always causes problems for me. I like to use the add-on, web development. It lets me test and experiment on the web for IE. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359
Also try adding float: left or margin: 0; or padding: 0; to see if one of them fixes the bug. Hope this helped.