# How can I prevent IE from displaying a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We all knows that IE has so many problems in opening html and rendering css files.

I want IE to show nothing when open a page.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should seriously start to make your application compatible at least with IE9. Its respect of standards is very good.

Comment: Ok, I'll admit this made me laugh

Comment: IE is a pretty good browser these days, but even if it wasn't, that's a dispicable way to treat people who happen to be using it.

Comment: Start by [providing the good headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#10305733).

Comment: You don't choose what your users view their site in. They do. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you should consider instead of showing nothing to exploit f.e. the newest Java holes and try to write a exploit that installs Chrome or Firefox instead. That would be much more convenient.

Comment: The web is all about being inclusive. IE represents perhaps 20% of web users, excluding them (and any other browser you incorrectly identify as IE) is the antithesis of inclusiveness.

Comment: As others have said, IE9, or even 8, is a decent browser. You could put in a [banner](http://www.ie6countdown.com/join-us.aspx) recommending visitors using the dreadful IE6 to upgrade their browser. If you don't like IE at all, there are [other banners](http://theie9countdown.com/join-the-cause)

Comment: I don't understand these comments. He's not asking if it's a good practice blocking IE users, he's asking how to block a given browser. The reasoning behind that decision is his responsibility. Should I downvote people who asks about CSS3? Or Canvas? Or Javascript? Because I'm a fan of Internet Explorer 1.5...

Comment: Duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690175/blocking-modern-ie/14690446#14690446 You'll note that this question wasn't closed; this is because (a) the questioner included more detail about what they'd already tried, so it looked like they'd put in some effort, and (b) they had a more legitimate reason for needing to do it. It's still not ideal, even then, but he got +9 votes and you got -3 for basically the same question. Gotta be something to learn from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use conditional comments and clear out your page!

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Please choose a better browser!';
}
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: not with IE10, you can't.

Comment: IE10 is pretty good. Which means you wont need to disable it for IE10 most likely.

Comment: the question didn't specify which versions of IE he wants to block.

Comment: Yes. But it begins with *"We all knows that IE has so many problems in opening html and rendering css files."*

Comment: Well, yes, but we also all know that's not true (even as far back as IE8 if you make a few allowances). The question itself is flawed, so we can't make assumptions about what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [jQuery plugin](http://jreject.turnwheel.com/) too.