# Different input sizes in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

When building a form I have come across some weird differences in sizing and spacing between Firefox and Google Chrome.

[image]

First off, in Firefox there's a pixel difference between the first input in each column.

Moreover, text inputs have different heights, also the space between the textarea and the input below is different making it impossible to align everything properly.

But the most peculiar thing is, the textarea and text inputs have the same bottom margin, but in Google Chrome elements coming after them aren't aligned.

```
.input {
  // ...
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Where are these differences coming from and how should I fix them?

**Update** [Normalize CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) doesn't fix any of this except for the one pixel difference on the top.

Code for this form: https://jsfiddle.net/jLcojhq0/2/

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936753/css-reset-for-chrome ?

Comment: Each browser has a default set of CSS rules it applies to any page, before any site-supplied rules are given. You simply want to overwrite and normalise these browser defaults, so perhaps research [**CSS Normalize**](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: CSS Normalize doesn't fix any of this except for the pixel difference on the top.

Comment: Ok Add that information in to your question.

Comment: @mplungjan The accepted solution for this question, which is applying Normalize CSS, fixes only the pixel difference on the top. I added a notice about this.

Comment: Your fiddle code looks strange to me… You are using label tags pointlessly (missing properties); you are toying with the box-sizing property, which can raise difficult conceptual problems, specifically cross-browser one — what is more, using the * universal descriptor; you are using rems (relative ems) to cloud up the issue a bit more. I suggest you rewrite your markup canonically and make you css as straight as can be. Then we will try to help you.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas I have updated my fiddle according to your suggestions. However I cannot get rid of the `box-sizing` because then the inputs overflow out of their containers.