# Position relative center screen and round corners

Tags: css, position, rounded-corners

I have this css :

```
#content_search
{
position:relative;
top:50px;
width:650px;
border:5px solid #111;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px / 5px 5px;

}
```

In all navigators as firefox , chrome , etc see fine , perfect ! but in explorer 9 see bad and in all versions of explorer , no can put center in the screen always go to the left or in other cases if i change something to the right

It´s possible center the div and no use div align=center

By other side it´s possible works in explorer this :

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px / 5px 5px;
```

For round corners into explorer

Thank´s regards

Comment: Do you have the [right header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#10305733) ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think `border-radius: 5px 5px / 5px 5px;` is valid. What would that `/` be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set `border-radius` for all corners to be the same unit, you don't need to specify positions.  Just `border-radius: 5px;` works fine.

If you want to center a container element within it's parent div, use `margin: 0 auto;`.  In theory, you can also set the parent div to `text-align: center;` and the child div to `display: inline-block;`, but I've found the margin method to be less buggy across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#content_search
{
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  width:650px;
  border:5px solid #111;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content_search">
        <span>My Content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `margin: 50px auto;` to center your div (the 50px in the shorthand margin would replace the `top:50px;`). Remember that when using the both left and right margin's to auto, you must set a width on your div

http://jsfiddle.net/galenw/LWQfA/