# DOM issues in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I've developed an application that I had tested in Chrome and Firefox but then upon testing in IE I noticed a few things weren't working quite as they should so I made a couple tweaks and everything seemed to be working as it should.

However, as if by some sort of magic when I was going through another round of testing in IE I started noticing that I was getting a lot of debugging errors that I had previously been getting.

They all seem to be to be DOM related with IE being unable to get the value of properties because the object is either null or undefined.

I was having none of these issues previously and I have absolutely no idea what might have changed to be causing this but does anyone have any experience of this sort of issue and have some suggestions as to how to resolve the issue?

I've had a look through all the different pages and functions I've been working on the last couple hours but can see nothing obvious that might be causing this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the correct [DOCTYPE and header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly/10305733#10305733) ? If so, and if you cleared all cache problems, then we'll probably need more details.

Comment: You have no details in your question we need code, errors, lines etc if you want answers

Comment: What are the exact errors?

Comment: Do you have any console.log() statements in your javascript? Does it work if you first load the developer console (hit F12)? That could be the issue, but beyond this, we can't help you without any code to look at.

Comment: It is happening on each page now so I don't really think it's going to be beneficial to post every line of code as well as all my functions that get called.

I was just wondering if there was something that might be causing it to happen application-wide since it was working on all pages before but even pages that have not been amended are now throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of IE come with a pretty decent script debugger.  If you press F12, a developer tools window will pop up.  Click on the "Script" tab and start working your problem from there.  Its not as robust or efficient as firebug or chrome's developer console, but its better than nothing and more often than not can get you pointed in the right direction when it comes to squishing IE bugs.

Comment: Yeah I've been using the F12 developer tools and can see exactly where the issues are occurring but they were not previously causing issues so there must be something else that I've done that is causing these issues to arise now but I cannot for the life of me find where! :(