# google docs iframe - change padding

Tags: angularjs, iframe, google-docs

I have an embedded `iframe` that has been created publishing a google doc.
The `iframe` automatically applies a large padding to its `body` resulting in the text being a very narrow and ugly column. I have to change that.

I have tried to create a custom directive:

```
app.directive('iframeWithStyle', [function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('load', function(){
               var iframe = element[0];
               var grabbedElement = iframe.querySelector("body");
               // -> grabbedElement is null here
        });
    }
}}]);
```

which is applied to:

```
<iframe iframe-with-style
        src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/somethingABC123/pub?embedded=true">
</iframe>
```

but `iframe.querySelector` returns `null` and `iframe.contentWindow.document` results, [as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe), in

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I have looked at a workaround but I have a feeling that it's overkill (ex: [safe cross-communication with messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153)).

I tried to fight the padding with some css applied to what I can reach.
For example:

```
iframe {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

css applied to the `body` of the `iframe` seems to be simply ignored.

Once upon a time there were some convenience attributes, such as [`marginwidth`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). Tried that too. 
I was also wondering if google does not offer some "sugar" but googling around did not help.

Note: it really does not have to be an `iframe`, but I need to show that formatted gdoc within the app in a way that it is readable; and for that I need to reduce that padding.

---

Adding a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XIkgPe7ecLyFfhq1Q3Sv?p=preview

Comment: Add html element code to which you are applying the `Directive`

Comment: I have added the html code to which I am applying the directive.

Comment: Once look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @SaiUnique, but the `iframe` is served from google. That's the problem.

Comment: I think it's better to have a parent element to styles the `iframe`. just style the parent instead of `iframe`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/6554634

Comment: @Mr_Perfect - I saw that one. It's not really clear to me how I could change css with that and still I have the feeling that it might be an overkill.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with a plunker?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: sure. tnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the last portion of your url from `true` to `false`.

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s2nOQZ39dKD-hsmox5twmmKKkuXzOopT1eXFbMh5DeE/pub?embedded=false

The demo includes use of all of the embedded elements:

`<iframe>`, `<embed>`, and `<object>`

## [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/LPosRgGNBMFHQAov6796/)

When you set `embedded=true` Google server will add a class named `.c1` to the `<body>` of the content inside the `<iframe>`

> ```
> .c1 {
>     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
>     max-width: 468pt;
>     padding: 72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt;
>  }
> ```

That's just plain reckless of Google if you ask me. I suggest that you set padding on the content itself and set `embedded=false`.

Comment: This is a step forward. Thanks! However, there's a "Published by Google Drive ... " box that gets added once setting `embedded=false", in all the scenarios <iframe>, <embed>, and <object> in your plunker.

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis You're not the only one that doesn't appreciate Google's heavy handed styling of published documents. Here's something that'll help: https://gdoc.pub/

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne -gdoc.pub is open source. I will have a look at the repo to understand how they ultimately did the trick.

Comment: You are very welcome @NoIdeaHowToFixThis Until you figure out gdoc.pub, you can try adding padding or margins to the document itself. Not the greatest of choices but that's the double edged sword of Google services: free but spotty control, plus documentation is never complete because they change things often.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use an `iframe`. You can send a CORS request to `GET` your document in javascript using a regular `XMLHttpRequest`. The response is an html document which you can read, modify or render.

See this answer for some example code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965010/8932511